# How to rename key of array with Arr::only helper?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, helper

I'm using `Arr::only` to fetch values from an array by their key, however I need to rename the `ShortDesc` key to use snake case not camel case. Is this possible with `Arr::only` or do I need to use an array_map?

Here's my brilliant code.

```
$myArray = Arr::only($targetArray, ["title", "shortDesc"]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly use [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#available-methods) for this instead of the helper methods:

```
$array = [
    'title'          => 'The title',
    'shortDesc'      => 'The short description',
    'someOtherValue' => 'foobar',
];

$newArray = collect($array)
    ->only('title', 'shortDesc')
    ->keyBy(function ($item, $key) {
        return Str::snake($key);
    })->toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code: https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Arr.php#L367

No, it's not possible to achieve what you need by only using Arr::only function.
You're gonna need some more.